# I want to do an SQL query for every member in the members table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, member

How do I do that?

I have a table with,at the moment, 3 members. For each one of these members I want to add a row to another table. Should I use a while inside a while? Or a Foreach loop?

This is what I have so far.

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM members";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

// Do I add a new while in here? Do I use a for loop?
```

}

Comment: That depends on what data you are inserting , would you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: I have a table called 'aanwezigheid' in dutch, which translates into availability. The table looks like this
|Aanwezigheid|
|email| Date | Adres| City|

I already have Date, Address and city stored in variables. I just need email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your table info :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

 mysql_query("insert into aanwezigheid set email='{$row['email']}', 
   date='{$your_date_var}',
   city='{$your_city_var}',
   address='{$your_address_var}'" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `insert` statement to add a set of rows to another table:

```
insert  OtherTable
        (email)
select  email
from    Members
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with just a single query.

```sql
INSERT INTO anotherTable (email) SELECT email FROM members;
```

You can read more about the [`INSERT ... SELECT` syntax in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: Can you tell me whether there is a mistake in this query?
-
-
"INSERT INTO availability (email, address, city, date) VALUES (email, '$address', '$city', '$date') SELECT email FROM members";

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake. The syntax is described in the documentation I linked. You want something along the lines of `INSERT INTO a (x,y,z) SELECT x,y,"foobar" z FROM b`.